# AngularJS inject element in [] issue

Tags: angularjs

why we need to put injection element '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider' in [ ], i found some tutorial videos that they just remove them and working fine, so i remove the same as well, but facing problems when deploying to web server with following error.

My question here is why we need to put the injection element in [], thanks.

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A %…es%2Fangular%3Fv%3DZGvZMulw2S5nigpn4yQz50dopAtRo-XYhjiW0UOpfnM1%3A25%3A449 (http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A %%E2%80%A6es%2Fangular%3Fv%3DZGvZMulw2S5nigpn4yQz50dopAtRo-XYhjiW0UOpfnM1%3A25%3A449) )

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.router', 'ngTouch', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'ngAnimate'])

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider,  $urlRouterProvider) {
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/category');

  $stateProvider
        .state('category', {
            url: '/category',
            templateUrl: '../../app/CategoryViewer/Category.html',
       controller: 'CategoryController'
    });
}]);
```

Comment: It is for minification. When you minify your JS the engine will replace variable names etc. As we know angular hacks up named parameters for its injection, so when the minification changes variables names angular can't find the modules to inject. giving the string names int he array aliases them. It no longer looks at the variable names but at the string in the array instead. If you don't minify your JS it makes no difference either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After minifying angular is not able to locate injected modules.. So, either define them or use `ng-annotate` .

I just love to go with Inline array method to avoid application breaking and easy code..

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

MyController.$inject = ['$scope', '$route', 'Item', 'items', 'utils', 'shade'];

angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('MyController', MyController);

function MyController($scope,$route,Item,items,utils,shade) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know,
Injecting using [] syntax grants that after minification process, angular will be able to find our controllers, services and so on.